# Comparação entre datas não está funcionando

Tags: php

Pesquisei aqui mesmo e achei uma solução para comparar datas, mas para mim não está funcionando a `strtotime`

```
$dataVencimento = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dados->VENCIMENTO));
 $dataAtual = date("d/m/Y");
 echo $dataAtual;
 if(strtotime($dataVencimento) < strtotime($dataAtual))
 {
        $situacao =  "<span class='label label-danger'>VENCIDO</span>";
 }
```

O valor de `dataVencimento` é 15/09/2018 e a `dataAtual` é 18/09/2018, portanto é menor e deveria entrar no `if`, mas não entra.

Comment: creio q este link pode ajudá-lo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722806/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função [strtotime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) reconhece formatos americanos de datas (normalmente MM/DD/AAAA) então converter diretamente de DD/MM/AAAA pode causar problemas.

O que você pode fazer é comparar dois objetos data que são retornados pelo strtotime usando um padrão reconhecido como `AAAA-MM-DD`:

```
$dataVencimento = strtotime($dados->VENCIMENTO);
$dataAtual = date("Y-m-d");

if($dataVencimento < strtotime($dataAtual)) {
    // Vencido
}
```